# RXJS - Handling 404 error on Instagram API

Tags: angular, rest, instagram-api

I'm using the Instagram API that doesn't use OAuth `https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{tag}?__a=1`

It works like a charm, I get the JSON and I am able to manipulate it the way I need, however, I'm getting an error when the **tag** doesn't exist. I get the 404 error **(as HTML instead of JSON)** and I'm not able to read the header to get `ok` or `status`. I looks like the error prevents the script of getting the `response`.

I am trying to get the response type to either return the data or null (in case the hashtag doesn't exist).

Can somebody help me?

```
getPictures(tag: string) {
    const BASE_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' + tag + '?__a=1';
    return this.http.get(BASE_URL)
      .pipe(
        map(
          (response: Response) => {
            console.log(response.headers.values()[0]);
            const data = response.json();
            return data.graphql.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_media.edges;
          }
        )
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should use `catchError` from RXJS like this:

```
getPictures(tag: string) {
const BASE_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' + tag + '?__a=1';
return this.http.get(BASE_URL)
  .pipe(
    catchError((err) => {
      if(err.status === 404)
         //DO SOMETHING
      } 
      return EMPTY;
    ),
    map(
      (response: Response) => {
        console.log(response.headers.values()[0]);
        const data = response.json();
        return data.graphql.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_media.edges;
      }
    )
  );
```

}

---

**EDIT** 
Concerning the "EMPTY", it's from RXJS and it allow to return an empty observables to be consumed by the "map" function ;)

```
import { EMPTY } from "rxjs";
```

Comment: dude, that works flawlessly. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @iconio you're welcome, I edit my answer to add the purpose of 'return EMPTY' ;)

Comment: Hey @Ben bro quick question... is there a way to prevent the execution of the `map` in case there is an error?

Comment: @iconio I'm not sure but you can try to use one of those (never or throw): http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/empty-never-throw.html
But if it doesn't work, try to deal with the fact that in your map, the response value will be empty if EMPTY is return, so a simple if to not execute your code will work..

Comment: gotcha. I'll check it out. I really appreciate you help bud!